# Error when uploading wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

when uploading wordpress plugin

Show me

You can not move the file that was submitted to the folder wp-content/uploads

Answer (score 0):

Seems the permission to your upload folder is not set to writable by group. Set the permission level to CHMOD 777.

Comment: i do that but same problem